# Move logic into controller in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined this variable within my view

```
<% value_one.each do |s| %> 
  <% document = current_user.documents.where(skill_id: s.id ) %>  
<% end %>
```

So I'm finding the users documents based on the skill_id (s).

But I am wondering how i can move this logic into the controller and assign it to say @documents. I am unsure on how to pass the params s.id to the controller though?

Am I thinking about this wrong, or is there a simple way to do this?

### Update

Based on the answer below my controller looks like so

```
def index
  @skills = Skill.all
  @documents = current_user.documents.where(skill_id: @skills.map(&:id)).all
end
```

I now have 1 single query (thankfully)

```
Document Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "documents".* FROM "documents" WHERE "documents"."user_id" = $1 AND "documents"."skill_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70)  [["user_id", 1]]
```

Comment: It might be more appropriate to put this logic into a model instead of the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're querying your documents in the least efficient way. If your `value_one` has 100 items, you're performing 100 queries.

Instead, you should do a single query for all the items in question:

```
# Assuming 'value_one' is available....
@documents = current_user.documents.where(skill_id: value_one.map(&:id)).all
```

You will have to actually store/map the objects to whatever values are in `value_one`. A simple solution would be to retain your current loop and find the object from the already loaded list of objects:

```
<% value_one.each do |s| %> 
  <% document = @documents.select { |d| d.skill_id == s.id } %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes i noticed my query for `document` is very poor, hence why I am looking to improve it and find out the best practice in this situation. Thank you for your help..

Comment: ok im getting `undefined local variable or method value_one` but i know you mentioned assuming value_one is available..how would i go about that?

Comment: oh wait a sec i think i understand what you mean now.. Ive updated my question to show my current controller, if you could confirm this is right (though by looking at the query now I think its right)

Comment: the idea is where does 'value_one' come from?

Comment: @meagar would you be able to assist with a way of accessing `s.id` in a partial or maybe refactoring my code to enable what i am trying to achieve <a href='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256604/accessing-values-through-ajax-called-partials'> here </a> please

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a function with one parameter. Assigning it to a global variable will not work, since you need that parameter for the query. So I'd say you could do

```
def userDocumentsForSkill(sid)
  return @current_user.documents.where(skill_id: sid)
end
```

... or similar and in your template:

```
<% value_one.each do |s| %> 
  <% document = userDocumentsForSkill(s.id) %>  
<% end %>
```

Not tested this, but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have ANY logic in the view.

Assuming that you have connection between document and skill (skill has_many documents) you can do `document.includes(:skill)` or `joins(:skill)`. You can add additional conditions here.

This will generate only one query to the database, and your view will be cleared from any logic.

If you want me to provide full code please update question with controller for that particular action.