# Accessing values through ajax calls and partials in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking to see if there is a better way to iterate through `documents` for each `skill` win my app as my current implementation is causing me issues when using ajax

My Models

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skill
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :documents
end
```

Within my view `public/index` I show all my `Skills` and each of the `documents` that a user has attached to a particular `Skill`

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @skills = Skill.all
    @documents = current_user.documents.where(skill_id: @skills.map(&:id)).all
  end
end
```

View

```
<% @skills.group_by(&:year_group_name).each do |key, value| %>
  <h3><%= key %></h3>
    <% value.group_by(&:aspect_name).each do |key_one, value_one| %> 
      <h4><%= key_one %></h4>
        <% value_one.each do |s| %> 
          <% document = @documents.select { |d| d.skill_id == s.id } %> 
            <li><%= s.skill_description %>
            <%= render partial: 'shared/documents/document_form', locals: { document: document } %>
            </li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

document_form

```
<% if document %>
  <% document.each do |doc| %>
    <%= doc %><!-- renders image if exists for user -->
  <% end %>            
  <%= render template: '/documents/new' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render template: '/documents/new' %>
<% end %>
```

When I create a document it is done via ajax and calls my `create.js.erb`

create.js.erb

```
$('.doc_upload').html("<%= j render(partial: 'shared/documents/document_form', locals: { document: @documents }) %>")
```

create action in documents controller

```
def create
@document = current_user.documents.new(document_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @document.save
    format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: success_save_msg }
    format.js
  else
    format.html
    format.js { render action: 'create.js.erb' }
  end
end
```

end

My problem occurs when I render the `create.js.erb` (so when validation fails for example)

You can see that I am passing the local `@documents`, which when i call `document_form` is iterating through all of the users documents, as opposed to just the documents for the particular skill.

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you rephrase your question. It seems you have too many questions under 1 thread and I'm a bit confuse about your `real` problem.

Comment: @Finks I have restructured my question, hopefully this makes more sense now, thank you

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your code properly, but I didn't find where you define \@documents variable in #create action. Only \@document. Maybe there is any before_action that fetches all user's documents?

Comment: Also, you could rewrite your query in index action like this:
current_user.documents.where('skill_id is not ?', nil)

Comment: @hedgesky apologies, you are right I did have a before_action that fetches all users documents which was being called in the create action, ive removed that, so now @documents is only declared in the `public/index`.. What Im trying to achieve is to only show the documents that belong to the user for that particular skill. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens because you're trying to use the partial `shared/documents/document_form`. That partial is expecting the `document` variable to be an array instead of a single object. We can see in your view that you've initialized `document` with a list of documents, the `select` method returns an array based on the condition.

In the `create` action, you've initialized `@document` as a Document object, hence when you used `@document` as your value for `document` in that partial, the partial view will not render your expected results.

Either create another partial that can handle your expected view, or refactor your current partial to handle different data types of `document` variable.

Edit:
So basically, in `document_form` partial, you're calling `each` method on the local variable `document` right? You can't call `each` on `current_user.documents.new(document_params)` which is the value of the `document` variable when you called the partial through ajax.

Comment: thank you for your answer, could you give an example of how I can handle this please, not quite sure what you mean

Comment: or better yet are you able to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265610/cant-submit-form-after-validation-fails-rails as i have done some refactoring

Comment: I've provided additional info, hopefully you get it this time.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, but turns out was nothing to do with that.. would you mind deleting the answer and ill delete the question as this wont help anyone in the future, appreciate your assistance though, thanks